# Can't build C++ program using Sublime Text 2, Windows 8

Tags: compiler-construction, build, compilation, build-process, sublimetext2

I think many of you are using or used to use Sublime Text 2 editor, on windows 8. I have strange error: C++ programs can't be built. My goal is to use Sublime Text 2 to build and run simple programs, so that it can show me the output in the window below, Xcode or Codeblocks style.

My C++.sublime-build (which are the default settings):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When i compile a simple hello world program, it compiles and runs fine, and the output is shown on the lower panel of sublime text, exactly like I want it.

But If I run a more complex program such as below:

```
//  main.cpp
//  LongestIncreasingSubsequence
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


    int n;

    cin >> n;
    vector<int> nums(n);
    vector<int> lis_so_far(n);
    int final_longest = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> nums[i];
        lis_so_far[i] = 1;
    }
    int so_far;
    for (int j=n-1; j>=0; j--) {

        so_far = 0;

        for (int i=j+1; i<n; i++) {
         //   cout << "hi" <<endl;
            if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
              //  cout << "hello" <<endl;

                if (lis_so_far[i] > so_far ) {
                    so_far = lis_so_far[i];
                    //cout << so_far << endl;
                }

            }
        }
        if (j<n-1) {
            lis_so_far[j] += so_far;
            if (lis_so_far[j] > final_longest) {
                final_longest = lis_so_far[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << lis_so_far[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << final_longest << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

, it gives me a missing limits.h error, even though I have cygwin installed. Isn't ST2 supposed to know where the c++ libraries are?:

```
C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\main5.cpp:11: limits: No such file or directory
[Finished in 6.5s with exit code 1]
```

If I comment the #include limits line, it builds, but when i run it, it gives me a permission denied error, even though there isn't a command prompt running:

```
/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/i586-cygwin32/bin/ld: cannot open output file C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop/main5.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas? I just want ST2 to function as Xcode or Codeblocks would.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sublime console "error". It's because you never terminate the last compile. for example.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
cout << "it's a program" << endl;
cin.get() // system pause
}
```

When you run this first time, you compile with success, but, as you are calling `cin.get()` to pause, the program never terminate, and keep opened.

And then, if you try to compile again, you gonna see the permission error, because the program still running. Remove the pause command and you are clear of error.